# Integrate power bi report with mobile APP

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk, powerbi

I want to develop android and iOS app using Flutter
and I want to display power bi reports into my APP
but I don't want to use I Frame or web view for this purpose,
I want to know if there is any other way of doing so? for example using power bi SDK or maybe using http request Rest API if there is a solution I'll be so thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use PowerBI Embedded for this. It's not going to be as easy as simply opening PowerBI Desktop and building some charts and deploying them, but I believe PowerBI Embedded was developed for this exact purpose.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/power-bi-embedded/

Comment: Can I get power bi report in json (rest api) ?

Comment: PowerBI is the visualisation tool used to take your data and render it on a page. It would take json as an input but it wouldn't send it as an output as this would completely defeat the point of a viz tool. If you are wanting json output, I'd suggest you get your ORM to send it to your frontend app, however this would then require that you either use a plug-in vis tool or build one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way. Whatever you use, it will boil down to Power BI elements rendered in an iframe in a web page displayed in a browser.